# ios material design cosmic mind tab bar implementation

Tags: ios, material-design, cosmicmind

Currently I am using [material design](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/wiki)  in ios project.
I am not able to achieve these tabs (Beauty,Yoga,Recipes) [attached screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4nzy.png). Is this can be achieved by using this library or I have to make my own.
Thanks for Any help.

Comment: Did the sample project help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CardTableView sample](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Graph/CardTableView) is where you can find the complete project demonstrating how to make the desired look using `PageTabBarController`.